# How to emit/broadast an event upon clearing all filters in ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Is it possible to emit an event to $rootScope upon triggering the clearAllFilters method in ui-grid (without editing the library)?

To give some context, I have a custom filter which requires a method be called once the 'clear all filters' menu item is clicked.  I had intended to include a watcher within the component e.g:

```
$rootScope.$on('clearAllFilters', function(){ });
```

However I can't find any way to emit such an event from the clearFilters method.

```js
// snippet from custom filter code

angular
    .module('my-ui-components.grid')
    .controller('MyCustomFilterController', function (_) {

        vm.inputValue = '';
        vm.removeFilter = removeFilter;
        vm.updateFilter = updateFilter;


        //  this method is called successfully on clicking the individual clear button / x
        //  however unable to call it programmatically upon clicking the 'clear all filters' button
        function removeFilter() {
            vm.inputValue = '';
            vm.colFilter.term = '';
        }

        function updateFilter() {
            vm.colFilter.term = parseCapacity(vm.inputValue, fromUnit, vm.toUnit);
        }


        // attempt at watching for filters being cleared however no event emitted to do so
        $rootScope.$on('clearAllFilters', function() {
            vm.removeFilter(); 
        });
```

```html
<!-- Custom filter template -->

<input type="text" class="ui-grid-filter-input" ng-model="vm.inputValue" ng-change="vm.updateFilter()"
       placeholder="{{vm.colFilter.placeholder}}"/>
<div role="button" class="ui-grid-filter-button" ng-show="vm.inputValue" ng-click="vm.removeFilter()">
    <em class="ui-grid-icon-cancel" ui-grid-one-bind-aria-label="aria.removeFilter" aria-label="Remove Filter">&nbsp;</em>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your code in Plunker?

Comment: Hi Maxim have updated to include snippet as difficult to add plunkr due to the number of dependencies involved.